# How to emit particles evenly within single particle setting

Tags: particles

How to emit particles evenly from verts / faces within single particle setting?

For example, for the default cube, I want to emit 80 particles in 10 frames, in other words, each vertex should emit 1 particle together per frame. (Note that this is a simple case to show what I'm talking about, not a specific one)

Comment: If you have a method that is preferable to you, do you believe you should share it? Compare and contrast it?  Working Blender file/script/nodes is always nice. Readers want to see the alternative. This is in reference to your comments on my proposed answer below.

Comment: Your visual sample would be nice to see.  Blender is visual.

Comment: 1. I shouldn't have asked this question if I was satisfied with my current solution. Right? :)  2. I'm sure you got the point here, just... either your way or mine creates extra objects in order to do so, and it got some limits obviously. Now I may guess there wouldn't be any better solution, but still keep some hope on that.

Comment: Interestingly enough there was a question here at BSE recently where the author seemed to have an answer immediately after posing the question.  I think many people could find that question if it actually merited the time.  So I did not really understand how that question fit in the "I truly need a answer" model.  It was more of "let me ask and answer my own question?.  I thought it was humorous. So this is a light response to your question 1.  You have the freedom to choose.

Comment: Your question 2.  No I did not get any [point] prior to you writing the comment.  So now I know your working state because you expressed it in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Blender Internal Render with Particle Info Node for Material Nodes**

[image]

- Image below. 16 Layers of Particles Systems modified with a Python Script.
  Vertices of a Cube.

[image]

- Image Below.  An image meant to be more readable with the particles placed in a plane.  Pulsed and Batch alternating.  Spiral motion is a typical consequence of the Particle System and very little effort of the Python Script.

[image]

- Image Below.  Particles with Turbulence.  One Force example.

[image]

- Image Below.

[image]

**Technique**

[image]

In the image above are 4 particle systems.  You may use 10.  Each Emitter particle system is copied via the Keystroke <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. User preferences allows particle system to be duplicated with fresh unique copies.  See user preferences Editing/Duplicate Data and enable Particle System Duplication.  Of course an object can have multiple particles systems.  The script assumes 1 per object for no particularly sound reason.

- If you can copy a mesh easily you can copy a mesh with a particle system easily.
- The N particles system has the [Start] and [End Value] set to different numeric value M. M >= 0 and  M < N in the simplest case.  See Script below.
- Copying Emitters and Manual modification of the values takes (log N + N ) steps.
- Example is Verts emission.  Faces emission is an easy switch.
- Clearly if you wanted ((vertex or face) * large number) particles then a script could modify the particle system [Start] and [End] values. (`frame_start`, `frame_end`)
- The Emitters are in a group for selection convenience.

**Script**

- Use at your own risk. Standard Disclaimer. Please test and improve.
- Select the group of Particle System emitters before running the script.

...

```
import bpy 
import datetime
import math

def delay_particles():
    print("Delay Particles")
    print(datetime.datetime.today())
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

    so = bpy.context.selected_objects
    limit = (len(so))
    n = 0
    for x in range(0,limit):  
        so[x].particle_systems[0].settings.frame_start = n
        so[x].particle_systems[0].settings.frame_end = n
        n = n + 1

delay_particles()
```

Comment: Thanks but what if the mesh contains thousands of verts?

Comment: The script should help you in that regard.  Blender is powerful.   I have not tested thousands of verts for your question.  That requirement should be in you original question.  Please change your original question.

Comment: You wrote verts above. Is that your intention?  Did you intend to write particles?

Comment: Tested, it seems to set start and end to 0, then all particles emit in one frame, not batches.

Comment: I actually mean that how to emit particles from each elements in batches, instead of one after one or emit all in one frame.

Comment: Please make all adjustments to the original question.  At this point I do not understand you.  You need to be clear with requirements.

Comment: Now I got your point. It does work. Actually I can also do this by similar ways without scripting, or with addons like Animation Nodes, etc. But I think I certainly mean how to make it by a single particle system. Sorry if something misleading in the question. However, I'll take yours as the final answer if no other better solution coming.

Comment: If you have a method that is preferable to you, do you believe you should share it? Compare and contrast it?   The actual script/nodes in concrete form is something readers can appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Just select emit from verts under particle settings.